# Execute method after response

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer, grand-central-dispatch

I am stuck in one interesting problem as i want to execute a method after 3 second but also want to check whether i got response of that method or not.

If i not got the response in 3 second then that method will not be executed.

Using code:

```
Timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0 target: self selector:@selector(receiveMessageWebservice)userInfo: nil repeats:YES];
```

This will run `receiveMessageWebservice` in 3 second of interval. But problem is sometime response not come in 3 second it take more time then i got two or three response same time.

I don't want so.

Please help.

Comment: Set a BOOL value at response, When response come change it value and call the receiveMessageWebservice method according to the bool value.

Comment: okk but the thing is that this method will be called after 3 second of interval. how to do that

Comment: whenever the response not come invalidated the timer.

Comment: **Waiting** for an asynchronous task is the completely wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

When you request for the Web Service just invalidate the timer and recreate it in the response success/failure block.

In this way you can successfully run the service request after every fixed interval without requesting multiple times

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, network calls cannot be time guaranteed . As i assume , you want to retry for a response till it doesn't come to you.

As i feel you should not use timer here, instead rely on web service completion and failure block to reinitiate the re-fetch of web service. If the response comes in failure block , then only retry.